# how can we assign a ORDER BY in two seperate fields in MySql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

how i set order by for two separate fields in mysql

CODE

```
$sql = 'SELECT q.question_id, a.answer_id, q.question_name, a.option_name, q.display_order AS ques_order, a.correct, a.display_order AS opt_order FROM questions q JOIN answers a ON (a.question_id = q.question_id) WHERE test_id = '.$m_test_id.' ORDER BY ques_order, opt_order ASC';
```

error message:

> Mysql­Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your My­SQL server version for the right syntax to use near '­ORDER BY ques_­order,­ opt_­order ASC' at line 4

```
ORDER BY ques_­order,­ opt_­order ASC;
```

Comment: Can we have the structure of the table and the complete query ?

Comment: Have you terminated your string with a semicolon `;`?

Comment: @ Adrien Lacroix $sql = 'SELECT q.question_id, a.answer_id, q.question_name, a.option_name, q.display_order AS ques_order, a.correct, a.display_order AS opt_order 
     FROM questions q
      JOIN answers a ON (a.question_id = q.question_id)
     WHERE test_id = '.$m_test_id.' ORDER BY ques_order, opt_order  ASC';

Comment: @ Voitcus yes i end the line using ;

Comment: The error part is just before order by clause....check variable $m_test_id. having any value or not

Comment: You could try to put quotes around `$m_test_id` as `WHERE test_id = "'.$m_test_id.'" ORDER BY...` etc.

Comment: This is the error My­SQL server version for the right syntax to use near '­ORDER BY ques_­order,­ opt_­order ASC'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's something wrong with `$m_test_id`; it's probably empty and causing issues with the SQL grammar. Consider using prepared statements:

```
$sql = 'SELECT q.question_id, a.answer_id, q.question_name, a.option_name, q.display_order AS 
    ques_order, a.correct, a.display_order AS opt_order 
    FROM questions q 
    JOIN answers a ON a.question_id = q.question_id 
    WHERE test_id = :test
    ORDER BY ques_order, opt_order ASC'; 

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':test' => $m_test_id));
```

Besides that, you should find out why `$m_test_id` was empty in the first place.

If you're not using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) you can use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) but note that it's deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: I removed my answer, because ours is just better... +1